# Transformation of OGR style data

Tags: gdal, ogr, coordinate-system

I have been using GDAL/OGR in a project and it is going quite well. I have been re-projecting data from various source formats into a single CRS (using the C# bindings), but one issue I have come across is with the associated OGR style information.

Most of the font sizes in the source documents are stored in "map ground units", so if I just copy the OGR style directly the text size will be scaled up or down depending on the differences in the map units.

So my question is, what is the best way of converting the map ground units in the style specification from one CRS to another, or in pixel units?

Many thanks for any help you can provide,